# Installing Node on Centos 6.8

Tags: node.js, centos

I'm trying to install nodejs on Centos 6.8 using these instrcutions:

http://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-and-npm-on-centos/#

When I run
`yum install nodejs`

But I get the following errors

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 0:5.12.0-1nodesource.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: nodejs-5.12.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) for package: nodejs-5.12.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nodejs-5.12.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: nodejs-5.12.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 19):

Best way to install nodejs (latest version) on centos 7: (Make sure you are a sudo user)

1. Open terminal and type: `cd ~`
2. Then type: `wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz` (Must check the latest version change the version name accordingly)
3. Then: `sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xzvf node-v10.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/local`
   (Must check the latest version change the version name accordingly)
4. Verify by using: `node --version`

Comment: The question specifically mentions "Centos 6.8", but your answer addresses Centos 7.

Comment: This worked for me on Centos 6.10. Anyway, I couldn't install a newer version like 12.0.0, so I installed 10.15.1 as in the example. Thanks!

Comment: i was able to install this on centos 6.9

Answer (score 7):

Try it before install:

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
yum update
```

my problem was in cached packages ...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you'll need to install gcc-c++ and make before install nodejs using yum.

Try this:

`$ yum install -y gcc-c++ make`

`$ curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`

And then:

`$ yum install nodejs`

And confirm it using:

`$ node -v`

http://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-and-npm-on-centos/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for alert me about my answer, I really did not know, but I edited it.
I hope it is ok now :)

Comment: I had followed these instructions, when I got that error, I should have put more info in the question sorry

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, if you do not need the latest node version, is in fact to use an earlier version of node, I had success with 10.23.  If you install node with nvm, you can install diff versions and try them easily.